# How to append to JSON with Java and Jackson

Tags: java, json, database, eclipse, jackson

I'm trying a simple test where the code appends a few json entries, however it is getting overwritten each time (the json file will only have 1 entry in it after running). I know I need to somehow create an array in JSON using '[]', but how would I go about doing that? Also, is there a better way to be doing this? I've been searching around and every library seems clunky with lots of user written code. Thanks

```
public class REEEE {

private static Staff createStaff() {

    Staff staff = new Staff();

    staff.setName("mkyong");
    staff.setAge(38);
    staff.setPosition(new String[] { "Founder", "CTO", "Writer" });
    Map<String, Double> salary = new HashMap() {
        {
            put("2010", 10000.69);
        }
    };
    staff.setSalary(salary);
    staff.setSkills(Arrays.asList("java", "python", "node", "kotlin"));

    return staff;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    File file = new File("src//j.json");        
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Staff staff = createStaff();

        try {
            // Java objects to JSON file
            mapper.writeValue(file, staff);

            // Java objects to JSON string - compact-print
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(staff);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you fixed this problem? Is any from below answers was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can add staff in List and then write the list to file as below,

```
List<Staff> staffList = new LinkedList<>()
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Staff staff = createStaff();
    staffList.add(staff);
}
mapper.writeValue(file, staffList);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I know you can pretty print json, but can you "pretty write" json so when I open the json file, itll have proper indentations and newlines?

Answer (score 0):

`Jackson` was implemented to parse and generate `JSON` payloads. All extra logic related with adding new element to array and writing back to file you need to implement yourself. It should not be hard to do:

```
class JsonFileAppender {
    private final ObjectMapper jsonMapper;

    public JsonFileAppender() {
        this.jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();
    }

    public void appendToArray(File jsonFile, Object value) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(jsonFile);
        Objects.requireNonNull(value);
        if (jsonFile.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File can not be a directory!");
        }

        JsonNode node = readArrayOrCreateNew(jsonFile);
        if (node.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) node;
            array.addPOJO(value);
        } else {
            ArrayNode rootArray = jsonMapper.createArrayNode();
            rootArray.add(node);
            rootArray.addPOJO(value);
            node = rootArray;
        }
        jsonMapper.writeValue(jsonFile, node);
    }

    private JsonNode readArrayOrCreateNew(File jsonFile) throws IOException {
        if (jsonFile.exists() && jsonFile.length() > 0) {
            return jsonMapper.readTree(jsonFile);
        }

        return jsonMapper.createArrayNode();
    }
}
```

Example usage with some usecases:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path jsonTmpFile = Files.createTempFile("json", "array");
        JsonFileAppender jfa = new JsonFileAppender();

        // Add POJO
        jfa.appendToArray(jsonTmpFile.toFile(), createStaff());
        printContent(jsonTmpFile); //1

        // Add primitive
        jfa.appendToArray(jsonTmpFile.toFile(), "Jackson");
        printContent(jsonTmpFile); //2

        // Add another array
        jfa.appendToArray(jsonTmpFile.toFile(), Arrays.asList("Version: ", 2, 10, 0));
        printContent(jsonTmpFile); //3

        // Add another object
        jfa.appendToArray(jsonTmpFile.toFile(), Collections.singletonMap("simple", "object"));
        printContent(jsonTmpFile); //4
    }

    private static Staff createStaff() {
        Staff staff = new Staff();

        staff.setName("mkyong");
        staff.setAge(38);
        staff.setPosition(new String[]{"Founder", "CTO", "Writer"});
        Map<String, Double> salary = new HashMap<>();
        salary.put("2010", 10000.69);

        staff.setSalary(salary);
        staff.setSkills(Arrays.asList("java", "python", "node", "kotlin"));

        return staff;
    }

    private static void printContent(Path path) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
        System.out.println(String.join("", lines));
    }
}
```

Above code prints 4 lines:
1

```
[{"name":"mkyong","age":38,"position":["Founder","CTO","Writer"],"salary":{"2010":10000.69},"skills":["java","python","node","kotlin"]}]
```

2

```
[{"name":"mkyong","age":38,"position":["Founder","CTO","Writer"],"salary":{"2010":10000.69},"skills":["java","python","node","kotlin"]},"Jackson"]
```

3

```
[{"name":"mkyong","age":38,"position":["Founder","CTO","Writer"],"salary":{"2010":10000.69},"skills":["java","python","node","kotlin"]},"Jackson",["Version: ",2,10,0]]
```

4

```
[{"name":"mkyong","age":38,"position":["Founder","CTO","Writer"],"salary":{"2010":10000.69},"skills":["java","python","node","kotlin"]},"Jackson",["Version: ",2,10,0],{"simple":"object"}]
```

Comment: Similar problem with `Gson`: [How can I use gson to create a set of key value pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975277/how-can-i-use-gson-to-create-a-set-of-key-value-pairs)